# How to access class object in aspx file from its code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my class in some namespace

```
public class UserObject
{
     public int MasterManagement_roleid = 0;
}
```

This Class have instance declare in code behind file like this

```
public partial class ContractorManagement_MaterialReturn : System.Web.UI.Page
{
            UserObject objUser = new UserObject();
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                 \\some code
            }
}
```

And In my aspx file i have some thing like this

```
 <%if(objUser.MasterManagement_roleid.ToString().Trim().Equals("-1")){ %> // This line error comes always please help
              //some tags to be displayed     
    <%} %>
```

Error Is 
server application '/' some thing like this

Comment: Is there a reason you're using server side code in your page rather than in your code behind? Just curious.

Comment: The name of aspx file is ContractorManagement_MaterialReturn.aspx

Comment: actually i have server code which can be used by some other aspx files so i cant use them in code behind
if i do so i cant use them twice ... and i have to retype it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `objUser` public.

Comment: Or protected will do I believe too.